# How to change argument of svg <g transform=scale(X)> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Hey.
Let's say that somewhere on my page I have SVG graphics. There is one group that I would like to re-scale when some event is triggered. How do I do that?
example code:

```
<svg onresize="getDivSize(evt)">
    <g transform=scale(13)>
        <rect id="Square" class="chart"
            width="80" height="20"
            fill="black"
            stroke-width="0px"
            rx="8" ry="8" />
         <text id="TextElement" x="13" y="15" fill="green">Text</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

I want to change scale(13) argument, to do that what should be in **function getScreenSize(evt) {...}**?
Or how achieve similar effect in different way?

**edit**
As for general idea I want to resize graphic without specifying fixed values anywhere. So my divs sizes are percentage based, now I just want my graphic to exactly fit my div regardless of its size. That's why I thought of JS changing scale() argument whenever event is fired (div resize). Function would put into scale argument computation of DivSize/rectBaseSize (x or y).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add an id attribute to the `<g>` and then try this:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_g_element").transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setScale(new_scalex,newscale_y);
```

or alternatively:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_g_element").setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + new_scalex + "," + new_scaley + ")");
```

On the other hand, why don't you just use a viewBox to have the svg contents rescaled automatically? Or are there specific constraints on what should be shown? It's also possible to do some of that with non-scripted solutions based on CSS3 media-queries, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAK5el8Uvrg (don't forget to check the description for links to the demo files shown in that presentation).

Comment: I haven't looked into viewbox yet, as so far I have 4 hour experience with SVG nad JS :P Anyway I look into it and CSS way also - thx for link.

Comment: how to add id to <g> dynamically??

Comment: @AbinayaSelvaraju e.g `yourElement.id = "foo";` or `yourElement.setAttribute("id", "foo");`.

Comment: I've been working with SVG for months, and I had NO idea about this "baseVal" business.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'just' want an SVG to scale to the size of a DIV, you can do that with CSS

```
#stretched-image {
    margin: 0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    display: block; 
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-image: url(../img/pic.svg); 
}
```